# Overwrite function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am developing a OpenLayers application which does dynamic classification of a vector layer. Therefore I am trying to loop through a specific number of thematic classes (categories) and define a filter for each class inside.

A OpenLayers object called *OpenLayers.Filter.Function* represents each of the filters. Each OpenLayers.Filter.Function overwrites the evaluate() function of the OpenLayers class.

My code looks like this:

```
var rules = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
    filter_x = function() {
    return new OpenLayers.Filter.Function({
            evaluate: function(attributes) {
                // some code to define the filter
                // uses specific values: array[i] & array[i+1
    }
    var rule_x = new OpenLayers.Rule({
        filter: filter_x,
        symbolizer: { fillColor: colors[i],
                    fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeColor: "white"}
    });
    rules.push(rule_x);
}
thematicStyle.addRules(rules);
```

Unfortunately this does not work. It seems that all filters execute the evaluate()-function of the last loop cycle.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Regardless of your issue note that any code below a `return` statement will not execute.

Comment: Thanks for your notice, of course you are right. I was a bit confused while experimenting with the code. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a closure over `i` which is **mutable**, that is, for all of your rules, the value of `i` will be the same in the end, namely, `numClasses - 1`. `i` is the same variable, shared for all iterations. No copy is created inside the body of the loop.

Here's the right way to do it:

```
var rules = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) (function (i) {
    filter_x = function() {
    return new OpenLayers.Filter.Function({
            evaluate: function(attributes) {
                // some code to define the filter
                // uses specific values: array[i] & array[i+1
    }
    var rule_x = new OpenLayers.Rule({
        filter: filter_x,
        symbolizer: { fillColor: colors[i],
                    fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeColor: "white"}
    });
    rules.push(rule_x);
})(i);
thematicStyle.addRules(rules);
```

In future versions of Javascript, you'll be able to do `let j = i` inside the for-loop, but for now on, you're stuck with these semantics.